# Difference between pretrained, finetune, feature extract

Tags: pytorch

I'm a little confused between the following terminology: pretrained, finetune and feature extract. I would like to use an out-of-the-box model to train a covid dataset. If I were to use resnet, would I be pretraining it? In what situation would I be finetuning the model or feature extracting?  Since the model is being pretrained, would it be wise to use the same weights being trained on the ImageNet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although fine-tuning may refer to some improvement of an existing model, it is not an improvement, but rather a transfer learning process to adapt a pre-trained model to new data.

I disagree with the fact that fine-tuning refers to transfer learning because it leads to confusion indeed.

Consequently, you fine-tune a pre-trained model in order to be able to learn efficiently on new data, thanks to the already learned data on the pre-trained model, which has more general extracted features.

Without using a pre-trained model, a model trained from scratch is not able to differentiate data easily and there is poor feature extraction.

https://d2l.ai/chapter_computer-vision/fine-tuning.html

If you train a pre-trained model on a new dataset, the new dataset should have some similarities with the original dataset from the first training. For instance, if you want to train a pre-trained dataset with an unknown animal (ex: pangolins), it should be ok if it knows already many other animals. But if you train it with completely new data (ex: 3d medical scans) without any similarity with the already known ones, it would be able to recognize if they are 3d medical scans, but it may not differentiate very well the different types of medical scans.

Consequently, in the case of completely new data like 3 medical scans, it would be better to train the model from scratch, unless the model have already learned on 3 medical scans pictures.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what if you were to train a pretrained model on a new dataset, which it has never seen before? Will it output the same results as a pretrained model, trained from scratch?

Comment: This is not a dumb question at all. Tahnsk for asking it. I've answered the question directly in the answer for more clarity.